# IDEA не запускает томкат на портах 8080 и 9090

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

По не понятной причине, после попытке загрузить сервак IDEA пишит что порты 9090 и 8080 заняты. Хотя они ни чем не используются, у меня только один проект в идеа папки.. Пару недель назад я запускал проект на порте 9090, но этот проект был стёрт.

Может ли такое быть что среда разработки помнит эти порты и считает их занятами, из за когдато запушенного проекта на одном из них ?

Пои попытке запустить через терминал, томкат запускается, но при попытке выключения я получаю эту ошибку!

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

При старте томката через терминал, он стартует, но при попытке добратся до ресурсов развёрнутого приложения ранее, я получаю 404.. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чём дело. При проверки порта на занятость не нашол никакой порт 8080 или 9090 от имени Java. OS Linux Mint.

На моём домашнем ПК, всё работает и при просмотре портов можно видеть статистику по использованию портов от Java.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4444/java
```

Должен ли порт 8080 слушать Java или же Tomcat ?

Comment: А как Вы определили, что эти порты ничем не используются?

Comment: Ну я на них запускал только 2 проекта.. Новых програм не устанавливал. У меня линукс и я апдейды не делал. Что еше может быть ? Только если IDEA считает каки то образом что порты заняты ..

Comment: Я бы для начала убедился, что эти порты действительно не заняты, ибо что-то мне подсказывает, что они и правда чем-то используются. Посмотрите с помощью, например, `netstat`.

Comment: Верите или нет, но я не нашол через эту команду какую либо инфу именно о этих портах. Но зато куча других!

Comment: Проверьте netstat-ом сразу после попытки запуска. Ещё как-то можно посмотреть какой процесс заюзал какой порт

Comment: 404 ответ вашего томката, который успешно запустился на порту 8080.  Или интелижи запустилась вместо него, судя по подписи внизу страницы ошибки. Просто он у себя не может найти приложение, соответствующее url. переданному через адресную строку в браузере. Скорей всего Ваш прожект не развернулся как положено.

Comment: томкат - это приложение, составленное на java, и работает на java. Порт будет слушать java. По id процесса можно выудить его "среду" ( командную строку и пр.) и по ней догадаться, какая именно прога на java слушает порт.

Comment: Изменил в Server.xml на 9191.. Всё работает! Ошибка так и осталась для меня загадкой. Только вот кроме Java 8080 и 9090 не кто не использует по проверки по netstat.